# How to clear only unnamed items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The title might be confusing but what I am trying to ask is say that you have two diamonds. One of them is named "Blat". How do I clear only the item that isn't named?

Comment: Are the names of the named items known, or do you really need to target all unnamed items? The latter would require detecting the absence of a tag, which as far as I know is impossible.

Answer (score -2):

right click both of them and they will split into named and unnamed

Comment: 1. IIRC you can't stack differently named items.  2. The OP is asking how to do this with commands.